# Excel: Find all values in a list that match another list as part of a COUNTIFS Statement

Tags: excel

I'm struggling with integrating a condition into my COUNTIFS statement. I have about 5 conditions which I've been able to easily work in, but I can't figure out the last one. The criteria range would be A1:A40000, and the criteria would count the number that match any value in a list of 30 text strings on Sheet 2, Cells A1:A40. Is this possible? I can get the result without the other conditions. Unfortunately, I do not have the flexibility to add a column next to A1:A40000 that checks to see if it is in the list.

Edit: Clarification per request.

Simplified version of what I'm doing. I need to count the number items (column A) that meet several conditions depending on the column in the entire data set. So, I need to find the number of items that have a value of "1" in column B - AND - a value of "YES" in column "C" - AND - a value of "OLD" in column "D" - AND - (the part I'm struggling with) column "E" must contain any one of the values that's in a completely separate range (call it Z1:Z40). The formula for the first 3 conditions would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,1, C:C,"YES", D:D,"OLD")
```

The final criteria in bold would be something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,1, C:C,"YES", D:D,"OLD",  **E:E,isnumber(match(E:E,Z1:Z40,0))**)
```

But that does not work...

Comment: I think it's kind of hard to understand your real problem with that much of information...

Comment: Jerry, thanks for the feedback. I updated it to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Columns B, C, D, E, etc. have details about the items in column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the range as a criteria. If you do that then your `COUNTIFS` function will return an array (one value each for each value in `Z1:Z40`) so you need a function to sum that array - I use `SUMPRODUCT` because it doesn't require array entry

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B:B,1,C:C,"yes",D:D,"old",E:E,Z1:Z40))`

That approach has some limitations - you can only use two "multi-item" criteria in one `COUNTIFS` function (and if you do one must be a column, the other a row, or you need to use `TRANSPOSE` to make it that way), and items in Z1:Z40 should not be repeated (or you may get double counting).

To overcome either of those limitations you can use `SUMPRODUCT` in place of `COUNTIFS` - with `ISNUMBER(MATCH` for the multi-item criterion. If you use `SUMPRODUCT` like that then it's better to restrict the ranges for efficiency reasons, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B100=1)*(C2:C100="yes")*(D2:D100="old")*ISNUMBER(MATCH(E2:E100,Z1:Z40,0)))`

You can add as many `ISNUMBER(MATCH` criteria as you want and `Z1:Z40` can be any single row/column range

Answer (score 0):

Let's say all your headers are in row 1 and the real data starts in row 2.
I would add a column on the end and put in the formula

```
=IF(AND(B2=1, C2="YES", D2="OLD", COUNTIF($Z$1:$Z$40,E2)),"YES","NO")
```

Then copy that down and any row where Column F was "YES" is a row that met all the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to use wildcards

```
=countifs(A1:D1;"*yes")
```

which counts all cell which contain 'yes'